# How to change the colors of the 3D planes with plotly

Tags: python, graph, 3d, plotly

I have these 3 coordinate planes and I need them to be seen in white with the axis lines in black. I've only managed to get the bottom plane to appear blank. I have checked the x, y, z coordinates and they seem to be fine, but the indices i, j, k I don't know if they are well defined. Any suggestions? and if it is possible to simplify the code I would also appreciate it. Plotly 5.14.1

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# lower plane points
x = [0, 1, 1, 0]
y = [0, 0, 1, 1]
z = [0, 0, 0, 0]
# indices of the faces
i = [0, 1, 2, 3]
j = [1, 2, 3, 0]
k = [2, 3, 0, 1]
# Crear figura del plano inferior
figura_1 = go.Mesh3d(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        i=i,
        j=j,
        k=k,
        color='white',
        opacity=1.0,
        showscale=False,
        hoverinfo=None,
        colorscale=[[0, 'white'], [1, 'white']]
    ) 

# right plane points
x2 = [0, 0, 0, 0]
y2 = [0, 1, 1, 0]
z2 = [0, 0, 1, 1]
# indices of the faces
i2 = [0, 3, 4, 5]
j2 = [3, 4, 5, 0]
k2 = [4, 5, 0, 3]

# Crear figura del plano derecho
figura_2 = go.Mesh3d(
        x=x2,
        y=y2,
        z=z2,
        i=i2,
        j=j2,
        k=k2,
        color='white',
        opacity=1.0,
        showscale=False,
        hoverinfo=None,
        colorscale=[[0, 'white'], [1, 'white']]
    )

# left plane points
x3 = [0, 0, 1, 1]
y3 = [0, 0, 0, 0]
z3 = [0, 1, 1, 0]
# indices of the faces
i3 = [0, 5, 6, 1]
j3 = [5, 6, 1, 0]
k3 = [6, 1, 0, 5]
# Crear figura del plano izquierdo
figura_3 = go.Mesh3d(
        x=x3,
        y=y3,
        z=z3,
        i=i3,
        j=j3,
        k=k3,
        color='white',
        opacity=1.0,
        showscale=False,
        hoverinfo=None,
        colorscale=[[0, 'white'], [1, 'white']]
    )

# Complete figure
figura_completa = go.Figure(data=[figura_1] + [figura_2] + [figura_3])

# design
figura_completa.update_layout(
    title= dict(
        text= 'Cube', 
        font=dict(size= 30), 
        automargin= True, 
        y= 0.95,
        x= 0.5,
        xanchor= 'center',
        yanchor= 'top'
    ),
    scene= dict(
        xaxis= dict(range= [0, 1], 
                   tickvals= [0.25, 0.75], 
                   labelalias= {0.25:'cs1',0.75:'cs2'}, 
                   showticklabels= True,
                   showgrid= False, 
                   title= 'Acción',
                   visible= True),
        yaxis= dict(range= [0, 1], 
                   tickvals= [0.25, 0.75], 
                   labelalias= {0.25:'psi',0.75:'edu'}, 
                   showticklabels= True,
                   showgrid= False, 
                   title= 'Social',
                   visible= True),
        zaxis= dict(range= [0, 1], 
                   tickvals= [0.25, 0.75], 
                   labelalias= {0.25:'arq',0.75:'ant'}, 
                   showticklabels= True,
                   showgrid= False, 
                   title= 'Carrera',
                   visible= True),

        hovermode= False,
        bgcolor='white'  # background white

    ),
    
    scene_dragmode= 'orbit'
)

figura_completa.show()
```

Result:
[image]